# Assigning value to a struct byte order

Tags: serial, data-type, struct

So i have struct:

```
typedef struct sendPacketStruct {
  byte header = headerByte;//0x55
  unsigned int time;//2 bytes
  int height;//2 bytes
};
```

And i do this:

```
    sendPacketStruct sendPacket;

    sendPacket.time = 84;//0x54
    sendPacket.height = 100;//0x65
    
    Serial.write((byte*)&sendPacket, sizeof(sendPacket));
```

But when i receive it at the other end the hex bytes are:

55 54 00 64 00

So the first byte is correct as the header 0x55, but the 2x 2 byte values time and height are there but shifted.

eg it should be 00 54 not 54 00

Comment: `it should be 00 54 not 54 00` ... why? ... is it causing a problem? ... the bytes are not shifted

Comment: Because if i read out the 2nd and 3rd byte to make the int I would get 0x5400 which is 21504  not 84 (0x54)

Comment: see 'endiannes' in wikipedia. this is why it is better to send text between systems.

Comment: `read out the 2nd and 3rd byte to make the int` ... how are you making the int? ... are you reading the bytes separately?

Comment: I would be reading the serial data a byte at a time as that arrive into an buffer array. When I detect a full packet in the buffer I would convert the various bits into the data. This is in a mobile app.

Comment: OK so it's actually acting correct for a little endian system, which I didn't know it was, I'm just only experienced in big endian network protocols. Thanks @Juraj

Comment: Either agree on an endian-ness (for transmission) among all systems sharing this data, or include an endian-ness indicator in the packet, and all receiver's agree to receive accept either one.

Comment: Note that today most CPUs, including AVR, ARM and x86-64, are little endian.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is that arduino is little endian, so the byte order is correct. I was just expecting big endian order as ive seen in some other network protocols. If that is desired instead I can just do some bit shifting and re-arranging.

Comment: The endianness of a protocol is defined by the protocol. In C there are functions `htons()` `ntohs()` etc for "Host to Network Short" and so on that set the correct endianness for the protocol.